# Particle System not working on multiple enemies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a particle system for when the enemy is destroyed. I have multiple enemies coming from the same path (using the same prefab) and the particle system is only working on the first enemy. Can someone tell me why it is not working on the others as well? Thank you.

EnemyShooting scrip (this is where the piece of code is for the explosion):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyShooting : MonoBehaviour {


[SerializeField] float EnemyLaserSpeed = 10f;
[SerializeField] float EnemyLaserFireTime;
[SerializeField] GameObject LaserBulletEnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxNumberOfHits = 1;
public Transform explosion;


int CurrentNumberOfHits = 0;
Coroutine FireCoroutine;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if(collider.gameObject.tag == "PlayerLaser")
    {
        if (CurrentNumberOfHits < MaxNumberOfHits)
        {
            CurrentNumberOfHits++;
            Destroy(collider.gameObject);
            Score.ScoreValue += 2;//The user will be rewarded 1 point

        }
        if (explosion)//EXPLOSION CODE
        {
            GameObject exploder = ((Transform)Instantiate(explosion, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation)).gameObject;
            Destroy(exploder, 2.0f);
        }


    }
}


void DestroyEnemy()
{
    if(CurrentNumberOfHits >= MaxNumberOfHits)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);

        EnemySpawner.Instance.OnEnemyDeath(); // Tell the EnemySpawner that someone died


    }

}

private void Fire()
{
    FireCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ShootContinuously());
}

void BecomeVisible()
{
    Fire();
}

IEnumerator ShootContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        GameObject LaserBulletEnemy = Instantiate(LaserBulletEnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        LaserBulletEnemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, EnemyLaserSpeed);
        EnemyLaserFireTime = Random.Range(0.5f, 0.9f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemyLaserFireTime);
    }
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    BecomeVisible();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    DestroyEnemy();

    }
}
```

EnemySpawner : (I thought this script might help in a way so I attached it)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{


[SerializeField] GameObject EnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxEnemies = 30;
[SerializeField] float EnemySpawnTime = 1.00001f;
[SerializeField] GameObject FirstWaypoint;
int CurrentNumOfEnemies = 0;
public int EnemiesToNextLevel = 7;
public int KilledEnemies = 0;
public LevelManager myLevelManager;
public static EnemySpawner Instance = null;
int timesEnemyHit;


IEnumerator SpawningEnemies()
{
    while (CurrentNumOfEnemies <= MaxEnemies)
    {
        GameObject Enemy = Instantiate(EnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemySpawnTime);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    if (Instance == null)
        Instance = this;
    StartCoroutine(SpawningEnemies());
    timesEnemyHit = 0;
    if (this.gameObject.tag == "EnemyHit")
    {
        CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
    }
}

public void OnEnemyDeath()
{
    CurrentNumOfEnemies--;
    /*     
    if (CurrentNumOfEnemies < 5)
     {
         // You killed everyone, change scene: 
         LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
     }
     */
    KilledEnemies++;

    if (KilledEnemies >= EnemiesToNextLevel)
    {
        LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
    }



    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it needs to be reset?

Comment: @jspcal What do you mean ?

Comment: Can you attach inspect view of your prefab? Both enemy and your particle system.